# if we do PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON before creation, will it affect after closing it

Tags: sqlite

i used PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;  before creating table in SQLite database.
i have created relations and my .db file is created. Now if i use that db file in other language, say PHP or Node then will that follow foreign key constraint ??

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) says:

> Foreign key constraints … must be enabled separately for each database connection.

You must execute the [PRAGMA foreign_keys](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) for each new connection in PHP or Node.

Comment: Any idea how to invoke this command using Sqlite3 node module.

Comment: That is a different question.

Comment: Okay. I figure it out. We can do using run command of sqlite. Thanks for your precious time.